# Magnetic fields inside hollow magnets, are the poles reversed?

Tags: electromagnetism

In a hollow magnet, a cube for example, are the magnetic poles reversed or is that a myth? In other words, if you consider the magnet in the image is hollow, and you place a smaller cube magnet inside it, would the magnets prefer to orient themselves like in example 1 in the image at the bottom? Or, are the poles inside the hollow cube somehow reversed, such that the magnets prefer a reverse orientation, example 2?

[image]
[image]

Note, this question is slightly similar to a previously asked question, it is not intended as spam but as genuine interest.

Comment: Hint: the cube magnet already has a smaller magnetized cube of metal inside it. Is it desperately trying to turn around?

Comment: You mean the magnetic poles are "reverse" on the inside, like in example 2?

Comment: re: your analogy, two bar magnets placed side by side with poles in same direction will desperately try to turn around, yet a single bar magnet the size of two magnets with poles in same direction will not.

Comment: It will depend on the exact geometry of the surrounding magnet. In other words, whether or not the magnet is long and thin, or wide and flat. I would suggest writing a small program to calculate the field for various magnet shapes if you have that skill, or maybe finding a program online that does this. I don't know what the answer is for the particular case of a cube though.

Comment: exact geometry is a cube, c^3

Answer (score 2):

If we are truly considering a hollow magnet, then example 2 is the preferred view. This is because magnets are made up of dipoles: you cannot have just a south pole, there must be a north. So, if you have a south pole that you've hollowed out, then the inside of said south pole must be north, because you cannot break apart a magnet to only have a south pole. By hollowing out the magnet, you have created a northern surface on the interior of the south pole, and a southern surface on the interior of the north pole. Theoretically, both configurations will sometimes work based on symmetry, but the first example is an example of an unstable configuration, while the second is an example of a stable configuration. What this means is that if there is any slight perturbation on either the hollow magnet or the interior magnet, then both configurations will tend towards the second example. You'd have to place a magnet perfectly in the first example to get it to work.

For any example that you wish to examine, you can apply the fundamental rule that magnets exist only as dipoles. If you'd like

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0$$

is the second Maxwell's equation and is taken as the mathematical explanation for why there are no such thing as magnetic monopoles. Thus you cannot have a magnetic north pole without an attached magnetic south pole. If you cut a magnet directly across the N-S line, you will just be left with 2 smaller bar magnets with a north and a south pole.

If you have a bar magnet that I will write simply as S-N, then what you actually have is a whole collection of tiny dipoles aligned S-N S-N S-N S-N S-N. You can see if you wish to hollow out the intertior, you need to remove a S-N pair, you cannot just remove an S or an N (in particular, you must remove a connected pair).

Comment: That makes sense. I have gotten contradictory answers so far, which is why I have tried to narrow down what I was asking (so a few seemingly similar questions if you look at this profile history. ) Roughly 50-50 actually on both examples, but I think most people are not that experienced with the subject.

Comment: What about horseshoe magnets? They are "hollowed out" sort of between the U shaped magnet, yet seem to not follow what you said, since they have a north pole on the "interior" surface as well as exterior.

Comment: @user612 That is not the interior surface, that is the exterior. The actual northern and southern surfaces are the tips of the U. Why does this make sense? Because again, there are only magnetic dipoles. The actual sides of the U will have a magnetic field around them coming from the tips of the U, but the dipoles are parallel to the side and so those sides do not really contribute to the magnetic field. The interior in that case would be INSIDE the tips, not in between them.

Comment: What about this diametrically magnetized cylinder magnet, it shows magnetic flux lines from north pole to south pole on a dipole,
https://imgur.com/a/Mogup8o

The image is from this paper https://espace.curtin.edu.au/bitstream/handle/20.500.11937/63348/261318.pdf

Comment: @user If you take a look at my final paragraph, you can imagine bending that configuration (keep in mind that there are much more than trillions of these tiny magnetic poles aligned, so any slight curvature is negligible to any tiny dipole, but globablly you can achieve that bent shape). That is exactly what your images are there. The hollow region would still be physically inside the N or S poles, not in between them.

Comment: @user612 Perhaps you are confused about what I mean by exterior and interior. If you are exterior to the magnet, then there is some path to the exterior surface of the magnet that does not require you pass through said surface. Likewise if you are interior, you must pass through the magnet to touch the exterior surface.

Comment: I am just trying to fit what seems contradictory, as contradictions do not exist. 

This hollowed out cylinder magnet shows a northern surface of the interior of the north pole, and southern surface on interior of south pole, with magnetic field lines from north to south,
https://imgur.com/a/Mogup8o

Comment: re: confused about what I mean by exterior and interior. If the hollow cylinder magnet is accurate (https://imgur.com/a/Mogup8o), and it were to close itself at the ends to form a hollow sphere, would then the interior of the south pole become a northern surface?

Comment: @user612 I can think of several configurations that would work for the hollowed out cylinder, or it might be the case that it's just a mislabeled diagram. You'll have to do a little more digging or thinking, but the basic principle is the same, it has to be made of tiny magnets

Comment: seems to be quite high level, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002197971731069X. the magnetic field direction appears on multiple drawings, https://i.imgur.com/udMTO0R.png

Answer (score 0):

We use the fact that magnetic field $B$ can be seen as arising from a collection of dipoles, and a permanent magnet can be seen as a collection of dipoles all aligned.

Consider the following pattern:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Each A represents one dipole. The field goes from base to tip of the A, then curves around to each side in a loop. Therefore for this arrangement the $B$ field is from bottom to top inside the magnet, and from top to bottom at the sides outside the magnet.

Now cut a hollow out. The field in the middle depends on the shape of the hollow.
For a wide thin hollow you get

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAA---------------AAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

The field in this hollows goes in the direction from bottom to top.

Next consider a long narrow hollow:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA--AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

The field in this hollow goes from top to bottom (like the field at the side of the magnet).

Finally for a cubic hollow in a cube I don't know the answer but one can see from the above that it is not self-evident and one would have to do the calculation! My intuition is that it will come out quite a small field so it's hard to guess the direction.